# How to solve $3 - 2 \cos \theta - 4 \sin \theta - \cos 2\theta + \sin 2\theta = 0$

Tags: trigonometry

I have got a bunch of trig equations to solve for tomorrow, and got stuck on this one.

Solve for $\theta$:

$$3 - 2 \cos \theta -  4 \sin \theta - \cos 2\theta + \sin 2\theta = 0$$

I tried using the addition formula, product-to-sum formula, double angle formula and just brute force by expanding all terms on this, but couldn't get it.

I am not supposed to use inverse functions or a calculator to solve this.

Tried using Wolfram|Alpha's step by step function on this, but it couldn't explain things.

Comment: Try to write it as $-8\sqrt{2}\sin^3\left(\dfrac\pi4-\dfrac x2\right)\sin\left(\dfrac x2\right)=0$, then it is much easier to solve.

Comment: @Hakim That's what W|A gave me, but I couldn't understand how it got to that.

Comment: I must admit that it isn't easy to arrive at that expression at first place, so you can use Vadim's strategy which is much simpler and requires much less work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x = \sin(\theta), y = \cos(\theta)$

$$3 - 2 y -  4x - 2y^2+1 + 2xy = 0$$

Simplify, divide by $2$ and replace $y^2$ with $1-x^2$.

$$1 - y -  2x+x^2+ xy = 0$$

Factor

$$(x-1)(x+y-1) = 0$$

Now just solve $\sin(\theta) = 1$ and $\sin(\theta) + \cos(\theta) = 1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would this be the way to go for questions like this?

Comment: You have two methods. One is to try and express everything in terms of $\sin(\theta)$ or everything in terms of $\cos(\theta)$. The other method would be similar to this method where you try to factor your expression.

Answer (score 0):

Strategy:

1. Rewrite $\sin 2\theta=2\sin \theta \cos \theta$, and $\cos 2\theta=\cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta$.
2. Substitute $x=\cos\theta, y=\sin \theta$ to eliminate the trigonometry and get a conic section.
3. Analyze the conic section to find $x,y$ that solve it.  Hopefully not too many.
4. Go back to $\theta$ by reversing the substitution from step 2.

Comment: Uh oh… only if I had knowledge of conic sections…

Comment: Luckily the quadratic factors; see @Brad's solution.